# htaccess to hide some folders and seo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site with the following folder structure

```
/folder1
/folder2/folder3
/othfolder1
/othfolder2
```

I would like to obtain this

```
mysite.com -> will show content of /folder1 (without showing the folder on URI, ok for subfolders)
mysite.com/folder3 -> will show content of /folder2/folder3 (without showing folder2 on URI)
mysite.com/othfolderX -> will just remain as it is (/othfolder1 or /othfolder2 or so on), no rewrite
```

Is this possibile with htaccess rewrite? Will this be any problem with current seo and search results for the site?

Comment: For `mysite.com/othfolders -> will correct show other folders` how it will decide which folder like `othfolder1` or `othfolder2` it will go? Kindly explain more on same.

Comment: Sorry, i just mean any other folder will remain the same, so otherFolder1/ otherFolder2/ and so on

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ folder1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder3)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) folder2/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried this, but if I go to mysite.com it just redirect to mysite.com/folder1 and /folder3 to /folder2/folder3
What I would expect is that on the URI /folder1 and /folder2 would be hiddento the users

Comment: @Luca, yeah it shouldn't show users in browser, since I haven't done the redirect in my rules, could you please confirm once.

Comment: Nope, It do this:
if i type on the address bar mysite.com
and it redirects me to mysite.com/folder1

if i type mysite.com/folder3 it redirects me to mysite.com/folder2/folder3

Comment: @Luca, are you sure, you have copied exact same Rules I mentioned, `R=301` or `R=302` is not present in rules so ideally it shouldn't do that, if you could confirm that you have copied exact rules(I edited them 1 hour ago, present ones), then we could look further, because when I tested these they were not redirecting.

Comment: Yes exactly same rule copied

Comment: Looking at the network pane on developer tools:

`mysite.com    301    document/redirect     other`
`folder1/          301    document/redirect     mysite.com/`
`folder1/          200    document                  /folder1/`

Comment: @Luca, sure, also try clearing cache of your browser, because when I check these rules by `curl` command they run fine, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Luca, may be its picking from cache, could you please clear your browser cache once and try it, let me know then how it goes?

Comment: Done, nothing changed

Comment: @Luca, ok, could you please try in in private window for IE OR incognito window for chrome once?

Comment: Tried on private windows in Edge, same behaviour

Comment: @Luca, ok, could you please do let me know if you have any other rules in your htaccess file too?

Comment: Nope, nothing else in it

Comment: @Luca, Could you please confirm once is `.htaccess` and folder1 are in same path? Though I believe since redirection happening correctly then its only rewriting issue in UI, still wanted to double check with you once.

Comment: Yep, same folder :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ folder1/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(folder3)/?$ folder2/$1/ [L,NC]
```

Make sure you test it after completely clearing your browser cache.